# Write output from Excel data input form to different worksheets based on a value in a form field?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to  write the data from an Excel data input form to a different worksheet based on the value given in one of the fields. As an example, let's say I'm entering data about a vehicle inventory. I want to have multiple worksheets, e.g. "Hatchbacks", "Trucks", and "SUVs". If "Truck" is specified in the "vehicle type" field on the form, then all the data in the form gets written to the next blank row in the "Trucks" worksheet.

The only ways I can think of to do this are:

1. using a vlookup - but I can't see any way to tell it to output to different worksheets.
2. using an IF formula referencing the "vehicle type" column on the master worksheet - but this will yield lots of blank rows in each of the worksheets.
3. Using Power Query - but I've never used it and don't want to install an add-in.
4. Maybe some combination of formulas and a VBA macro - but what formula? (And I'm not very proficient with VBA macros.

Can someone please tell me what's the right approach and point me toward the best solution?